# Replacing hundreds of files with one simple check box check

Tags: c#, checkbox, conditional-statements

Is there a simple or a more compact way to do this with a large number of files with one check-box (checked/unchecked), i have i think few thousand lines to put inside the code and i can sort them by year, or by type:

```
private void CheckBox()
{
    try
    {
        switch (checkBox.IsChecked)
        {
            case true:
            {
                const string disable_picture100 = "images/disabled/picture100.png";
                const string picture100 = "images\\disabled\\picture100.png";
                Records[picture100].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, disable_picture100, content.FileRoot);

                const string disable_picture101 = "images/disabled/picture101.png";
                const string picture101 = "images\\disabled\\picture101.png";
                Records[picture101].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, disable_picture101, content.FileRoot);

                const string disable_picture102 = "images/disabled/picture102.png";
                const string picture102 = "images\\disabled\\picture102.png";
                Records[picture102].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, disable_picture102, content.FileRoot);

                UpdateImage();
            }
            break;

            case false:
            {
                const string enable_picture100 = "images/enabled/picture100.png";
                const string picture100 = "images\\enabled\\picture100.png";
                Records[picture100].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, enable_picture100, content.FileRoot);

                const string enable_picture101 = "images/enabled/picture101.png";
                const string picture101 = "images\\enabled\\picture101.png";
                Records[picture101].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, enable_picture101, content.FileRoot);

                const string enable_picture102 = "images/enabled/picture102.png";
                const string picture102 = "images\\enabled\\picture102.png";
                Records[picture102].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, enable_picture102, content.FileRoot);

                UpdateImage();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ignored
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: And all the filenames are like `picture100`,`picture101`,`picture102`,... ?

Comment: Different names, i have put picture100 for better understanding how the code look's like right now.

Comment: So where do you get filenames from?

Comment: They are on two separated folders, one named "enabled" and another one "disabled". They are on the same location on the hard drive. The worst part is the names of the files that i need to put them manually, and i thought that the code to be much simpler to handle this.

Comment: So how would you know which one is for which records? I guess this question is still unclear

Comment: This is done by me, manually, i have to choose what to be enabled and what not every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this roughly what you are looking for?

```
        string pictureName;
        string newPictureName;

        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>(); 

        foreach(var name in fileNames)
        {
            if (checkBox.IsChecked)
            {
                pictureName = "images\\disabled\\" + name + ".png";
                newPictureName = "images/disabled/" + name + ".png";

            }
            else
            {
                pictureName = "images\\enabled\\" + name + ".png";
                newPictureName = "images/enabled/" + name + ".png";
            }
        }

        Records[pictureName].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, newPictureName, content.FileRoot);
```

Let me know if not.

Comment: I've just updated the code to include the checkbox, let me know if that does what's needed

Comment: Can you add a list read option to read from, i think is better to put the names inside a list and then read them from there for both statements....Thank you!

Comment: @user2558921 I've incorporated Felix Av's filenames approach, is that what you meant?  I haven't run that code, but it looks about right

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>(); //suppose you have names of files in a list
foreach(var name in fileNames)
{
    if(checkBox.IsChecked)
    {
        Records[name].ReplaceContents
        ("images/disabled/" + name, "images\\disabled\\" + name, content.FileRoot);
    }
    else
    {
        Records[name].ReplaceContents
        ("images/enabled/" + name, "images\\enabled\\" + name, content.FileRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: //suppose you have names of files in a list - I can make one if it's better this way to handle them, and add inside all the pictures names.

Comment: yes, then it should work for you, and can be dynamically edited etc.

Comment: I suppose i need 2 list files, one for each state right ?...and how does the List "fileNames" knows where from to read this lists...sorry if it looks like a dumb question :)

Comment: no, as I saw, the name of the files only should contain picture100.png not the entire path, the path will be decided according to checkbox. As for where to get list from there are many options, you can check out "how to get filenames from directory" or something like that

Comment: Ok, i'm working on this to make it work...i'll let you know if i get it done right.Thank you.

Comment: Good luck! Let me know if there's anything more

Answer (score 1):

Using the code below you can specify a directory (where the string says "FilePath". It gets all files with the extension .png

Then it checks once if the checkbox is checked or not.
And then loops over all the files in the enumerator

```
        var allPngFilesInGivenDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles("FilePath").Where(x => x.ToLower().EndsWith(".png"));
        var fileEnumerable = allPngFilesInGivenDirectory.GetEnumerator();

        string partialPath = checkBox.IsChecked ? "enabled" : "disabled";

        while (fileEnumerable.MoveNext())
        {
            string file = Path.GetFileName(fileEnumerable.Current);

            string disable_picture = "images/" + partialPath + "/" + file;
            string picture = "images\\" + partialPath + "\\" + file;
            Records[picture].ReplaceContents(imagesPath, disable_picture, content.FileRoot);

            UpdateImage();
        }
```

Comment: Nice solution to use the file enumerator